# kubernetes Minikube : Node port service not accessible from outside

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to deploy simple spring boot REST service on minikube (Windows-10). Below are my configuration

**Docker file**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "/usr/share/myservice/minikube-spring-boot-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
ADD target/minikube-spring-boot-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  /usr/share/myservice/lib
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD target/${JAR_FILE} /usr/share/myservice/minikube-spring-boot-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
```

docker image is running fine and i am able to run the app.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 minikube-spring-boot-demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHO
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: minikube-spring-boot-demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minikube-spring-boot-demo
      tier: backend
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minikube-spring-boot-demo
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demo-backend
          image: nirajsonawane/minikube-spring-boot-demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minikube-spring-boot-demo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: minikube-spring-boot-demo
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30008
  type: NodePort
```

**kubectl get all status** 
[image]

**kubectl cluster-info**
[image]

**minikube logs** 
[image]

**Service Details** 
[image]

i am not able to access the rest endpoint using `service-ip:Nodeport/Uri`
**http://127.0.0.1:30008/hello**

**http://172.17.0.2:30008/hello**

Anything i am missing here? any inputs will be useful.

output of   **netstat -a**

[image]

Comment: Can you check wheather port 30001 is listening or not ? `netstat -tulpn`

Comment: updated output of netstat -a, Accepted port range is  30000-32767

Answer (score 2):

`minikube` is running in a virtual machine. Services can't be accessed through either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` out of the machine.

Try to run `minikube service minikube-spring-boot-demo-service`. It will show service details and open the service in the browser.

Comment: i tried using servie-ip:port but it still not working

Comment: connection time-out , i checked the logs of pod. No issue in pod

Comment: 2 possible reasons may cause the timeout. There are some firewall rules that drop the traffic head to the minikube virtual machine. Or, no route on the host(Windows 10) forwards traffic to the minikube guest. You can check both the host route table and hyper-v or virtualbox networking settings.

Comment: Thanks to checking this. Turnout to be issue with my widows. I need to run all commands as Administrator.It strange

Answer (score 0):

You can get you cluster ip using below command

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

then run below to get nodeport

```
kubectl get svc -o wide -n <namespace>
```

get the port of your NodePort Svc

then your application will be running on http://:port(svc Nodeport )

In your case it might be running on 
http://127.0.0.1:30008/hello