# Deploying Angular App on minikube and expose via port

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, deployment, minikube

I have issue with deploying angular app on minikube. I am not able to expose the running angular container on browser.

Below are my setup files.

### Minikube start command

```
$ minikube start --driver=docker
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-alpine AS node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-prod
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/shopping-wepapp /usr/share/nginx/html
```

### Deployment configuration file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: shop-cart
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: shop-cart
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: shop-cart
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: shop-cart
          image:  kavin1995/development:shop-cart-app-07-04-2020-14-00
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

### Service configuration file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: shop-cart-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: shop-cart
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort
```

### Port exposing command

```
$ minikube service shop-cart-service --url
```

Comment: well...what is the issue?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu after getting the URL , i cannot able to view the page , the port is not exposed yet. i cannot able to find out the issue.

Comment: What kind of error did you see in the browser?

Comment: @kitt i am facing the below error 
This site can’t be reached172.17.0.2 took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics

Comment: @Kavinkumar Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016395/kubernetes-minikube-node-port-service-not-accessible-from-outside/61022589#comment108030472_61022589

Comment: @Kitt No , the above link didn't helped

Comment: What is your host OS?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the use of the `docker` driver: the minikube IP is a container IP and cannot be accessed outside of the docker host.

The only way to expose the nodePort outside would be to publish the port on the **running** minikube container (which only expose this: `127.0.0.1:32771->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32770->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32769->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32768->8443/tcp`)

One way to do this would be (even if ugly) :

```sh
CONTAINER_IP=`minikube ip`
SERVICE_NAME=shop-cart-service
SERVICE_NODE_PORT=`kubectl get service ${SERVICE_NAME} --output jsonpath='{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}'`

iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport ${SERVICE_NODE_PORT} -j DNAT --to-destination ${CONTAINER_IP}:${SERVICE_NODE_PORT}
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -p tcp --source ${CONTAINER_IP} --destination ${CONTAINER_IP} --dport ${SERVICE_NODE_PORT}
iptables -A DOCKER -j ACCEPT -p tcp --destination ${CONTAINER_IP} --dport ${SERVICE_NODE_PORT}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use nodePort, you will be available to access the service from outisde the cluster.

To do it, first get the minikube ip from your command line:

`minikube ip`

It will return an ip X.X.X.X. After that, access your service from your browser: `http://X.X.X.X:31000`

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Comment: expose the port 80 in your dokcer file. add the line: `EXPOSE 80`. That’s going to tell Docker that your container’s service can be connected to on port 80.

Comment: Facing same issue after adding EXPOSE 80 to dockerFile